# Why does hostnamectl return arm64, but uname returns aarch64? (Ubuntu 20.04.2 on raspberry pi)

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, architecture, arm64

I have a raspberry pi running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Two different architectures are being returned depending on the command: **aarch64** and **arm64**. Why?

**hostnamectl**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: plex
         Icon name: computer
        Machine ID: 5d1b763f15314c999d1b33e60d8d556f
           Boot ID: bdd535b62f134f6a9216543b36deb678
  Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-1047-raspi
      Architecture: arm64
```

**uname**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname --all
Linux plex 5.4.0-1047-raspi #52-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Nov 24 08:16:38 UTC 2021 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Thank you! (I believe this is causing a problem. Trying to install something and it's looking for aarch64 and not finding it, but I can see there is a version for amd64.

Answer (score 3):

`aarch64` and `arm64` are the very same architecture. Most of the packagers and package manager uses `aarch64` name, but when it comes to systemd it uses `arm64`. You can find more information here:

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/db58f6a9338d30935aa219bec9a8a853cc807756/src/basic/architecture.c

In this code, `aarch64` is mapped back to `arm64`. Arm64 architecture is also used in the standard specifiers' man page (I have no idea which man page it is but here is the code: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/5efbd0bf897a990ebe43d7dc69141d87c404ac9a/man/standard-specifiers.xml).

This page informs you that architectures are listed in the systemd.unit man page. Here you got extract `man 5 systemd.unit`.

```
       ConditionArchitecture=
           Check whether the system is running on a specific
           architecture. Takes one of "x86", "x86-64", "ppc", "ppc-le",
           "ppc64", "ppc64-le", "ia64", "parisc", "parisc64", "s390",
           "s390x", "sparc", "sparc64", "mips", "mips-le", "mips64",
           "mips64-le", "alpha", "arm", "arm-be", "arm64", "arm64-be",
           "sh", "sh64", "m68k", "tilegx", "cris", "arc", "arc-be", or
           "native".

           The architecture is determined from the information returned
           by uname(2) and is thus subject to personality(2). Note that
           a Personality= setting in the same unit file has no effect on
           this condition. A special architecture name "native" is
           mapped to the architecture the system manager itself is
           compiled for. The test may be negated by prepending an
           exclamation mark.
```

From this short investigation, I deduce that systemd uses `uname` system call that prints `aarch64` and changes it to `arm64` internally.